Why is it plural for one example and singular for the second?

Have you got any bags left?

I saw in a bar this written

Karaoke Any song any language

Why is it not plural "any songs any languages" as in the first example?
Both meanings are the same.

Do you speak French? "any bags" is like «des sacs» 'some bags' while "any song" is like «n'importe quelle chanson» 'whichever song'.

"Do you have/have you got any X?" is used when enquiring about supplies of uncountable things (e.g. milk) or countable items. We normally use the plural for countable items even if the enquirer only wants one.
The karaoke sign is a different use of any. We know that a karaoke machine contains several/many songs, but what the notice is saying is "You may choose any song you like, in any language". Here, any means no matter which one.

We normally use the plural for these even if the enquirer only wants one. (even if uncountable things as milk)

@YvesLefol With milk, it is Do you have any milk? We normally use does not mean we always use.

In which cases you don't use plural ( with all uncountable nous)

Answer edited to clarify.


Have you got any bags left?

The question is asking whether a selection of bags remains from which one might make a choice of bag. Or possibly boxes containing multiple bags if the bag in question is like a small paper bag, not luggage.

Karaoke: any song, any language.

That sign means that one can choose to sing any song one wishes, and in any language one wishes.

For example, "Dogs are friendly" uses the plural "dogs" to refer to the species in general, while "The dog is friendly" uses the singular "dog" to refer to a specific animal. The choice between singular and plural depends on whether the speaker is talking about all members of a group or just one.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
